# laravel use artisan in custom file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron

I'm working on direct admin and in directadmin cronjobs you can just run files.
then i try to create a file like cron.php in public and use my cammands like this :

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
\Artisan::call('newsletter:send');
```

and when my cron run i have this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Artisan' not found in

how can i use Or Import Artisan class in my custom files?

Comment: laravel has a pre defined console classes for this which handles your cron https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan

Comment: @KhanShahrukh Do you read my question? how can i use artisan class in custom file

Comment: If you're in the public directory shouldn't your paths be `__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'` and `__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'`?

Comment: @RossWilson this was my mistake typing .. its true in my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply creating an instance of the app will not mean that your facades will just work as they will not be in the scope of the app.

To get your above code to work you would have to use the app to make the underlying instance of what the `Artisan` facade uses i.e.

```
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->call('newsletter:send')
```

That being said, you are basically reinventing the wheel with this one as Laravel comes with a much more elegant solution for this out-of-the-box https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling.

So, rather than creating another entry point for your app for one cron command you can instead use Task scheduling. Some extra advantages to this are:

1. You can define all of your cron jobs inside your app so you can see what jobs are actually set up more easily.
2. If you end up moving your app to a different server then you don't have to worry about setting up all of your cron jobs again.
3. If other developers end up working on the app they will have a better overview of what is going on as well.

If you don't like the idea of using Laravel's Task scheduling and you would prefer to define all of them in your crontab then I would suggest making a controller for your cron jobs and then using laravel's built in routing to handle the request for you.

Hope this helps!